# How to debug error "PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library)" when install php extension ?

Tags: php

I developed very simple php extension,  here's the source code:

https://github.com/jackey/nicequery

i did this:

```
phpize

./configure

make 

make install
```

no error output , everything's OK.

then i edited `php.ini` to enable it.

but got error `"PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library)".`

i checked the source code very carefully but not found any problem. :(

So can you give me any idea to debug the error like that and help to check the code where's the problem is ?

i fall into the stupid hole :(

Answer (score 2):

the problem is

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DL_EXTNICEQUERY

ZEND_GET_MODULE(nicequery)

#endif
```

it should be

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DL_NICEQUERY

ZEND_GET_MODULE(nicequery)

#endif
```